# incorrect integer value mySQL

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

Im receiving an error where I am using an incorrect integer value for userID_fk and target. The error comes up for values which have an integer as their data type and if its changed to text or varchar it will state a site has been created and the siteID will increase but no other data will be included. I want the user to input their username so its matched with its userID and inserted into userID_fk through python with Tkinter.

Below is the structure for my users and sites table

users:

```sql
 CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `userID` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `userName` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
 `userPassword` varchar(225) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
 `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `phoneNum` text NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(230) NOT NULL,
 `region` text NOT NULL,
 `accessLevel` int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`userID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10002 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

sites:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `sites` (
 `siteID` int(225) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `siteName` text CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
 `userID_fk` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `region` text NOT NULL,
 `risklevel` text NOT NULL,
 `siteType` text NOT NULL,
 `target` int(225) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`siteID`),
 KEY `userID_fk` (`userID_fk`),
 CONSTRAINT `sites_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userID_fk`) REFERENCES `users` (`userID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

Python code to insert a site into the sites table:

```py
def register_site():
    sitename_info = sitename2.get()
    username2_info = username2.get()
    region_info = region.get()
    risklevel_info = risklevel.get()
    sitetype_info = sitetype.get()
    targetpercent_info = targetpercent.get()
    # Sql code for writing the data that was written in the regsitering page. 
    cursor = cnn.cursor()
    sitequery = "INSERT INTO `sites`(`siteID`, `siteName`, `userID_fk`, `region`, `risklevel`, `siteType`, `target`) VALUES (NULL,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    sitequery_vals = (sitename_info, username2_info, region_info, risklevel_info, sitetype_info, targetpercent_info)
    cursor.execute(sitequery, sitequery_vals)
    cnn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    cnn.close()
    # removes the values in the entrys once the user selects that the registration was successful
    sitename2_entry.delete(0, END)
    region_entry.delete(0, END)
    risklevel_entry.delete(0, END)
    sitetype_entry.delete(0, END)
    targetpercent_entry.delete(0, END)
    Label(screen10, text = "Site Created", fg = "green", font = ("calibri", 11)).pack()
```

Comment: Do not include the column siteID during the insert.

Comment: I still receive the same error if I don't include the siteID... does it not matter al I have stated the value for siteID will be null?

Comment: why `int(255)`,`int(225)`?  what does `select version();` show?

Comment: Genuinely no idea I'm very new to this and I'm doing this for a coursework project. im trying to keep the data types the same as data in other tables but even without using them as integers I still receive errors.

Comment: siteID is auto increment and as such should not be included in the `insert...`. What's the value of `username2_info` from `username2_info = username2.get()` which you are trying to insert into an integer field `userID_fk`? I suspect it is not a number and instead is a string as the name implies.

Comment: I have entrys for each value and as I know what the userID is I have been inputting that to see where the errors may be coming from. I originally thought I could use a select statement within the insert statement to select the userID with the username I have inputted but I still receive errors.

Comment: ```sitequery = "INSERT INTO `sites`(`siteName`, `userID_fk`, `region`, `risklevel`, `siteType`, `target`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"``` Does not work? Also, then try typecasting the values manually, or try printing the values before the query to check it out.

Comment: yeah that doesn't work and I've tested the query through phpMyAdmin before using It in Python.. the queries work in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `username2_info` is the `userName`, you need to get the `userID` from the `users` table:

```py
sitequery = ("INSERT INTO `sites` (`siteName`, `userID_fk`, `region`, `risklevel`, `siteType`, `target`) "
             "SELECT %s, `userID`, %s, %s, %s, %s FROM `users` WHERE `userName` = %s")
sitequery_vals = (sitename_info, region_info, risklevel_info, sitetype_info, targetpercent_info, username2_info)
cursor.execute(sitequery, sitequery_vals)
cnn.commit()
```

Comment: I get a message saying a site has been created however nothing is inserted into the database..

Comment: It may be username does not exists in `users` table.  It works fine for me. Add `print(cursor.rowcount)` to show number of record inserted after `cursor.execute(...)`.

Comment: Its prints out that there's no records inserted and what do you mean by there may be no usernames in the users table..? I've had a look assuming it meant I have nothing in the table I have users there. I already have a piece of code similar to this one that inserts users into the database through python and that works fine so i'm not sure why this piece of code doesn't.

Comment: It means that there is no record in `users` table with the username you input into `username2`.

Comment: I just created a user in my users table with the username 1 and put 1 into username2 and nothing is still created. Would it matter if my username2 is a global variable in another function and that its just not pulling any of the data I have inputted.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong in your environment.  I create a test database based on your table definitions and insert an user into the `users` table.  Then using my proposed code to insert record into `sites` with the username I added into the `users` table, and it works fine.  Did you print all the values of `get()` to see whether they have the values you expected?

Comment: I rewrote the code for the inputs as it wasn't getting the values I expected and now it gets all the values and puts it into the database! thank you !